# Username/password authentication that works on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

At my school, we have to authenticate the the wireless network using a username and a password. Windows seem to handle much of the process automatically, so that the user only has to supply the credentials.

For better or for worse, I use Ubuntu 14.10. The default authentication setting for this network is "Tunneled TLS"; I leave "anonymous identity" blank. Several options were provided; I recall LEAP, TLS, and FAST. None of them worked.

How can I connect to this network the same way Windows does?

Comment: Is PEAP offered?

Comment: Can you check whether the wireless network drives was installed in your Ubuntu OS?

Comment: @vembutech I know that some network drivers are installed because other networks work fine.

Comment: @grawity The Ubuntu wireless connection GUI offers PEAP.

Comment: @grawity PEAP works. Thank you! (You can post that as an answer; probably a lot of people have this issue.)